# How do i concat two different dataframe using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

First dataframe1 is only a header of three lines.(only a string line)

myworking Distribution
We have our store in villages only
we worked for 52 Weeks from 09/16/17.

Second dataframe2 is my main working part with the header as below.

```
Item,item details,price,packcolor,flavour,total orders (in thousand),delivery time (in weeks)
1,Priceless chocklate biscuits,20,black,chocolate,16,3
2,Priceless chocklate biscuits,25,white,vanila,23,6
3,Priceless chocklate biscuits,20,orange,Orange,54,2
```

when i'm using beow statement :

```
df = pd.concat(dataframe1,dataframe2,axis=0)
```

its showing results in onecolumn in excel and also deleted the header of the dataframe2.

Comment: What is desired output? Maybe need `pd.concat([dataframe1,dataframe2],axis=1)`

Comment: What are the headers for df1? And what is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :-
I have place a test file , where first three lines remain the same.
while i was analysis the below second part
Path :- https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=test.csv